# Java EE batch file not running

Tags: jakarta-ee

We have an application made with Java EE which is running in a location. When I copy all files we see and execute the batch file, we get the following error:

> reading no help set found for null , cant find bundle for base name
>   .messages , locale en_us

Could anyone suggest what the problem could be?

The env. variables are the same as in the other system.

Comment: Is the base name really `.messages` with a leading period? Shouldn't it be `messages`?

Comment: yes it reads .messages , please help me i am stuck

Comment: Change it to `messages`.

Comment: this is resolved , i was suing a higher version of JDK